# Задать область для перемещения окна

Tags: c++, winapi, c++17

Задача простая:

- Создано окно с флагом "`Popup`"
- Нужно задать область, для перемещения этого окна

С помощью `SetWindowPos` не хочу этого делать, обработчик событий окна не хочу трогать вообще

Придумал как можно это сделать - с помощью `WindowMove`, отслеживание нахождения курсора мыши в нужной области окна и при нажатии лкм, передвигать окно, в принципе хороший вариант, но не могу сделать корректное перемещении окна, оно "прыгает" жестко.

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) == -32768)
    {
        if (isInBoxLocal(x, y, width, height) || bMove == true)
        {

            bMove = true;

            pCustomWindow->moveWindow
            (
                pCustomWindow->getMousePosGlobal().x,
                pCustomWindow->getMousePosGlobal().y
            );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        bMove = false;
    }
```

Собственно вопрос, не "кодил" уже много лет, решит возобновить, пока не "кодил", вышли несколько стандартов `с++`, может быть есть какая-то функция для этого дела специальная, чтобы не выдумывать велосипед? (Что - то типа `SetAreaMoveable(x,y,width,height)` -) )

---

UPD:
Нашел такой вариант - `SendMessage(pCustomWindow->getHWND(), WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MOVE | HTCAPTION, 0);`

Работает идеально, но если окно заезжает за области рабочего окна, область окна не обновляется, WindowUpdate не помогает...

Answer (score 1):

Для этого необходимо написать обработку события `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING`. В `lparam` будет содержаться указатель на структуру `WINDOWPOS`, изменяя которую можно контролировать размер и положение окна до того, как эти изменения применятся.